# How to make custom Helpers in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, methods

I'm fairly new to Rails, and I was confused as to how I could pass local variables outside the if...else statement. It looks like creating a method in the helper file is the conventional way to do this, but I wasn't sure how to do this.

So I'm trying to get the Author of a Mission. If the author of a mission doesn't exist, I want to use the author of its parent Syllabus (missions belong to syllabus). And then I want to print out the username of that author. I was able to do this when I was dealing with only one mission, like:

```
//controller
@mission = Mission.first
if !@mission.author.blank?
  @author = @mission.author
else
  @author = @mission.syllabus.author
end

//view
<%= @author.username %>
```

but I wasn't sure how to do this when I was dealing with a foreach loop:

```
//controller
@mission = Mission.all

//view 
<% @mission.each do |mission| %>
..(where do I put the logic of finding author? I can't put it in my controller anymore and it won't pass the @author variable outside the if else statement if I put the logic here in the view)..
<%= @author.username %>
<% end %>
```

My futile attempt was to create a helper:

```
def author_getter(mission_id)
  @mission = Mission.find(params[:mission_id])
  if !@mission.author.blank? 
    @author = @mission.author 
    return @author
  else
    @author = @mission.syllabus.author  
    return @author
  end 
end
```

and putting the below inside the loop

```
<%= author_getter(mission) %>
```

However, this didn't work. What would be the best way to pass on a variable outside the if...else statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your helper method is a little confused. Helpers shouldn't be poking around in `params`, they should just be doing things with the arguments they're called with. You're passing in a `mission_id` but not using it, you're also calling it with (apparently) a `mission` object when the parameter name indicates than an ID is being asked for. Also, you don't need to be messing around with instance variables in helpers, just plain old variables will do.

Adjust the interface to ask for a Mission object and then use that object:

```
def author_of(mission)
  mission.author.present?? mission.author : mission.syllabus.author
end
```

Or, since `mission.author` should be `nil` or there, you can take advantage of the falseness of `nil`:

```
def author_of(mission)
  mission.author || mission.syllabus.author
end
```

Then in your ERB:

```
<!-- Note that you should use the plural @missions for a collection, you'll have to fix your controller as well. -->
<% @missions.each do |mission| %>
    <%= author_of(mission).username %>
<% end %>
```

Of course, once we've simplified and corrected your helper, you might decide that it is too small to be worth bothering with; if so, then you could ditch the helper and do it all in ERB:

```
<% @mission.each do |mission| %>
    <%= (mission.author || mission.syllabus.author).username %>
<% end %>
```

However, I think you have this logic in the wrong place: this should be inside Mission itself so that everything (other models, JSON builders, ...) can take advantage of it. So, a method like this would make sense:

```
class Mission
  def real_author
    author || syllabus.author
  end
end
```

then you can say this in your ERB:

```
<% @missions.each do |mission| %>
    <%= mission.real_author.username %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This makes so much sense now! :) :)  I really don't know how I can express the joy and gratitude I'm feeling right now!!

Comment: 1 more question: When I use the 'mission.real_author', and I want to store that as '@author = mission.real_author', where would I define the @author variable? Would I have to do it within the .each do loop, or can I define it in the controller somehow?

Comment: @KeithRyu: When you have `@missions` already you'd want to use `<% author = mission.real_author %>` inside the iteration, that way the `author` doesn't leak out and cause trouble elsewhere.

Comment: I see - I was wondering because I heard that you shouldn't be defining variables in the view. I'm still slightly confused as to what should conventionally be in Models, Controllers, and Views. Someone told me that I should be writing in the Model a lot, and the controller should be very lean as well, but right now my controller is the most bloated- is this normal?

Comment: @KeithRyu: That's normal when you're starting out and not sure of what you're doing. Views are for presentation, variables in views are usually just shorthands for something else (such as `author`). Controllers route data from the outside world to models for processing and then route the results to views for presentation; they should be thin and tight. The bulk of your logic should end up in model methods. If you have a fat controller then you probably need a couple refactoring iterations to get everything in the right place, only experience (i.e. making mistakes) will teach you how though.

Comment: aah once I become more familiar, I should probably start looking at other people's open source code to get a feel for what they are doing. Again, Thank you so much @mu is too short !! (i dont think the '@' did anything lol)

Comment: Hmm, it still wasn't working so I reset my local database, and then it worked, but it wont work on production (and obviously I shouldn't reset the database on heroku). What should I do? Is there a way I can look at the database and see what the problem is?

Comment: What would be the best way to check that? (and so it is better to have NULL ?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11173/discussion-between-kibaekr-and-mu-is-too-short)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, you can do this in your loop without using a find.

```
//view 
<% @mission.each do |mission| %>
   <%= mission.author.username %>
<% end %>
```

Remember, you are iterating through all of your Mission objects. Once you have a mission object you can just access the author as you normally would.

Comment: Well, the problem is some Missions don't have authors, in the case that it was created as a nested field for Syllabus. In that case, it should be mission.syllabus.username, so I wanted the logic.

Comment: It's confusing, but essentially a user can create Missions by itself, or create a Syllabus and have many nested Missions within it. In the case that the Mission was created separately, 'mission.author' would work and is preferred, but in the case that it was created as a syllabus, 'mission.syllabus.author' would need to be the case. Later, I made it so that even if it was created as a  syllabus, it would pass in the author params to the mission author, but there are still a lot of missions without authors from before